# Laravel: One to Many Or Polymorphic Relation for Different Content types?

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-migrations

I have a table `contents` which has many types, for example `posts` , `albums`, `videos`.

the contents table migration is :

```
Schema::create('contents', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('ref_id')->index();
    $table->integer('type')->index();
    $table->string('title', 255);
    $table->text('description');
    $table->boolean('published')->default(false);
    $table->string('thumb', 255);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

and posts table migration is:

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->text('body');
});
```

the same idea goes for all other types like videos:

```
Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('youtube_id', 255);
});
```

To retrieve the full content now, I use hasMany relationship:

```
class Content extends Model
{

    public function posts() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post','id' ,'ref_id');
    }

    public function videos() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Video','id' ,'ref_id');
    }
    ...
}


class Post extends Model
{
    public function content() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Content', 'id' , 'ref_id')->where('type','1');
    }
}


class Video extends Model
{
    public function content() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Content', 'id' , 'ref_id')->where('type','3');
    }
}
```

As you can see, I manually added `types` where each type has a number , for example, content with type 1 is for posts, content with type 3 is for videos, etc..

I feel like my structure isn't that good and can be improved. I came across Polymorphic Relations in the documentation and I don't know if it will be good for my case or not.

Any Advice?

Comment: Polymorphic Relations seems to make perfect sense here. Your current structure is fine too but I believe you can classify it as a Polymorphic Relation too make it more clear for other developers.